# Join tables and sort by 2 different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have query that make a list of payments (payment table) and I would like to have it sorted by the date of the tasks (2 separate tables - quotedb and packaging) these payments are related to

My Query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM payments AS a 
LEFT JOIN quotedb AS b ON a.orderid = b.id  
LEFT JOIN packaging AS p ON a.orderid = p.id  
WHERE a.status='Pending' AND (b.moveday<'$today' OR p.datestamp<'$today')
ORDER BY b.moveday, p.datestamp
```

payments table example:

```
id payment   orderid
------------------- 
1  payment1  1
2  payment2  2
3  payment3  3
4  payment4  4
5  payment5  5
6  payment6  6
```

quotedb table example:

```
id moveday
-----------
1  05.07.18  > related to payments table id 1
2  08.07.18  
3  10.07.18
```

packaging table example:

```
id datestamp
-----------
4  06.07.18  > related to payments table id 4
5  07.07.18
6  19.07.18
```

I join results from the tables, but I have a problem with sorting, query seem to print the "packaging" table results unsorted, and then results from "quotedb" sorted by moveday

I want these results to be sorted by (joined moveday and datestamp)

Comment: I would question whether you really need separate tables for quoting and packaging. You could just have a separate column that identifies the stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM payments AS a 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT orderno, moveday AS sortdate FROM quotedb 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT orderno, datestamp AS sortdate FROM packaging
) t on a.orderno = t.orderno
WHERE a.status='Pending' AND sortdate<'$today'
ORDER BY sortdate
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION ALL` to combine `quotedb` and `packaging` tables. and use `grp` make a number to make `Order by` sequence number

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM payments a 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 grp,id,moveday AS day
    FROM quotedb
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,id,datestamp
    FROM packaging
) t on a.orderid = t.id
ORDER BY t.grp,t.day
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82e43c/5)

Comment: thx, but this is not sorting results as expected, query returns sorted result of the quotedb first, then sorted packaging. I updated the fiddle to be more visual. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68531b/1

Comment: I find `moveday`, `datestamp` i declare as varchar in my sample fiddle,if change to datetime it's correct http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8fba0/1

Comment: take a look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68531b/2 - but there is still something messed up, in real life out of nowhere i have couple results from packaging on top of the list that shouln't be there

Comment: OK,so you don't need to split order by `moveday` and `datestamp` only `order by`  id @Nita

Comment: query in the last fiddle sorting seem to be fine, except that in real life 2 (the same payments are show twice ( on top of results and then sorted in the middle),

Comment: i had the same id in the tables, so i need to change JOIN on column that is unique for both tables.

Comment: No problem glad to help